# Unable to start terminal

Tags: linux, pop-os

I am unable to start the terminal in Pop_OS!. Till yesterday everything was working fine but today when I started my machine and used super + T which is a default shortcut for starting the terminal in the genome it just wouldn't start. I also tried to start the terminal from the application drawer. It just wouldn't start. Any solution would be highly appreciated.

Comment: See if there is a hidden file named `.xsession-errors` in your home directory. Any error messages resulting from the terminal start-up attempt should go in there.

Comment: There is no file with that name in the home directory.

Comment: In my case an issue happened after trying to upgrade Python3. It's actually used when starting the terminal and in the new version there are missing some packages (sic!). I haven't found the solution yet but will probably try to install different  (alternative) sh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case an issue happened after trying to upgrade Python3 the day before. Python3 is actually used when starting the default terminal and in the new version of Python3 there are missing some referenced packages (sic!).

I installed different, random (alternative) sh .

[image]

After installing new sh I managed to restore old Python3 version by choosing it
`sudo update-alternatives --config python`

[image]

After that default terminal started to work again.